# How to batch download 1 million direct file URLs?

Tags: windows, download, download-manager, file-download

How can I download 1+ million files that are stored in a text file?

I have tried several download managers and they are very slow when importing URL lists. Currently I have waited for 20 hours on *Download Master*, and I have also tried *Internet Download Manager* (IDM) and *JDownloader*, but is there any other software that can process mass URL import and downloading faster?

The files that I'm trying to download are mostly image files - jpg, png, gif, around 200 KB each. And each image file's url is stored in new line in a text file.

Comment: What format are the files? How big are they? Where are you downloading them from?

Comment: They are image files mostly - jpg, png, gif, around 200 kb each, I'm downloading them from URL's

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? If it's Linux - this is super easy

Comment: It would be more efficient to either transfer these files via the Torrent protocol or combine them into an archive file (ZIP, RAR 7Z, etc.) on the host system before downloading them to the destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) you can use [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download everything in a file containing a list of URLs.

Put all the URLs in a file called `urls.txt`, you can run this command:

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

Comment: If you don't already have cygwin, just ensure Wget is selected as a package during the install

Comment: How can I add download folder to that command ? 
I tried 

`wget -i -P D:\folder\ urls.txt`

it shows an error: 

`Resolving d (d)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘d’
-P: No such file or directory
No URLs found in -P.`

Comment: I just moved cygwin64 folder to external disk and ran the command there. Everything works now. But it would be great if there were parameter for multiple downloads.

Comment: I also found multithread cmd `cat urls.txt | xargs -P 7 -n 1 wget -nv` (7 is max connections) maybe this is useful for someone.

Comment: Sorry, was away for a few days. I'm glad you found how to use it though

Answer (score 2):

In Linux this is super easy with `wget`

However I'm assuming you're a Windows user.

If this is the case, you can achieve similar results using Powershell if you're using Powershell 3 or above.

1. Create a .txt file in notepad with your full list of URL's
2. Open Powershell and `cd` to the directory where you've saved your urls.txt file. For example `cd C:\Users\jay\Documents`
3. Paste the following into the Powershell window: `Get-Content urls.txt | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest $_ -OutFile $(Split-Path $_ -Leaf)}`

Comment: This is working. How can I set multiple threads ?

Comment: Just encapsulate the code within the top answer provided here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel

Comment: Multithreading like that is pretty complicated - I suggest you just split your 1 million file list in 5 parts or something, then open 5 seperate powershell windows and run the same command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for efficiency, running a few jobs in PowerShell is probably one of the best approaches but it requires a bit of scripting expertise.

I filled a file with a million records and then timed a command to read it back, took 13.5s (I have a standard 7,200RPM HDD).

```
$down = New-Object "System.Net.WebClient"
Get-Content "C:\YourFile.txt" | Foreach-Object {
    $down.DownloadFile($_, $_.Split("\")[-1])
}
```

Just as a basic single-thread example but this will happily chug away in the background if time is not of the essence. Otherwise you could split up the file, either manually or programmatically, and use `Start-Job { //code here// }` for each section.

Of course this entirely depends on the format of your file and how you need to save them and such but all is possible in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small program for Windows called Mass Download that many times has helped me a lot: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Download-Managers/Mass-Download.shtml. Hope it can help you!

Comment: Can you give more details in order to help users?

Comment: It's a very small GUI program (no installation needed). Specify the TXT file with the URL list, then the destination folder and click Download. It downloads up to 5 files at a time and, in case a download isn't successful, it'll be resumed once all other files have been downloaded.